# Comprehensive sorting/paging/filtering service layer interface method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I'm trying to write a service layer method that will take all the necessary parameters that will allow me to get data from the repository in the way how a webforms grid would work.

The repository returns `IQueryable<T>`.

I came up with a model like this:

```
public class PagedModel<T>
{
    public GridSortOptions GridSortOptions { get; set; } //Enum for ASC and DESC
    public IList<T> Items { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

The method:

```
PagedModel<User> GetUsers(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate, int page, int pageSize, GridSortOptions sortOption);
```

Questions:

1. What parameters am I missing from this method?
2. What properties am I missing from the PagedModel?
3. How do I implement the method?

What I want:

1. Paging
2. Sorting
3. Filtering

Answer (score 1):

I find it nice sometimes to create a "Criteria" class that contains all the properties separate from the list of items you are searching for. This way you can use it as a model property that will automatically be bound on your search actions, pass it to service and repository methods (instead of a bunch of separate params), persist it in session if need be, have strongly typed filter properties specific to the current type you are searching for (ie User), have a supertype for holding generic paging or sorting.

Something like

```
public class UserCriteria
{
    public GridSortOptions GridSortOptions { get; set; } //Enum for ASC and DESC
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just been using the Telerik MVC components, they're open source and free. The nicest thing I've just found is that if you use `IQueryable<T>` as your datasource, it will automagically provide you with... paging, sorting, filtering and grouping (sure there's some bits I've left out) straight out of the box!

It might be worth looking at them.

Comment: The Telerik stuff is really nice.